# MVC 3 - Razor - Print value from model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to set the value of a label using Razor, I have a model and

```
<label id="status">
@{ 
if (Model.Count() > 0)
{
   Model.First().StatusName.ToString();
}                                                                   
}
</label>
```

If I put a breakpoint on Model.First().StatusName.ToString(); I can see that that expression has the value that I need, but I cannot see it when the page gets rendered -
Am I missing something in my syntax ?

Thank you

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to add `@` sign before `Model.First().StatusName.ToString()` to let Razor know that you are outputting something. Otherwise it will treat it as ordinary method call.

```
<label id="status">
@{ 
if (Model.Count() > 0)
{
   @Model.First().StatusName.ToString()
}                                                                   
}
</label>
```